# Trying to use railroad diagram to show the recursive nature of algorithm and how it backs up

Tags: diagram

I want to use a railroad diagram to show the sequence of steps an algorithm takes:

[image]

I want to say we start with "SCC scheduling". It then repeatedly calls "chunk scheduling". Then "chunk scheduling" repeatedly calls "group scheduling". When "group scheduling" finishes we go back up to "chunk scheduling". And then we back up one more step to "SCC scheduling" and repeat and if there is no more SCC then we go end state.

```
Algorithm:
  foreach SCC
     run SCC scheduling

SCC scheduling:
  foreach chunk inside SCC
     run chunk scheduling

Group scheduling:
  foreach Group inside chunk
     run group scheduling
```

I have been thinking about this for a long time and I am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm incorrect, but it seems straightforward to me...

[image]

Visual variation (different arrow positions)...

[image]

Comment: Actually I meant we go to the end from the "SCC" and not "group". But makes sense

Comment: *Technically*, the process would end at the last group from the last Chunk. Unless an SC exists with 0 Chunks.

Comment: Yes. That's true. You are right